# SciPy fails to install via pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, scipy, slurm

I try to install SciPy with pip on a [SLURM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slurm_Workload_Manager) environment. NumPy and some other python modules are already installed and working fine.

However, when I run:

> pip2.7 install --user --use-wheel scipy

or

> pip2.7 install --user scipy

I always get a huge wall of text ending with:

> error: Command "/sw/compiler/gcc-4.9.3/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -shared 
>   -Wall -g -shared  -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/integrate/_odepackmodule.o
>   -L/sw/env/gcc-4.9.3_openmpi-1.8.8/pkgsrc/2015Q4/lib -L/sw/env/gcc-4.9.3_openmpi-1.8.8/pkgsrc/2015Q4/lib -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -lodepack -lmach -llapack -lblas -lpython2.7 -lgfortran -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/integrate/_odepack.so" failed with
>   exit status 1
>
> ---
>
> Command "/sw/env/gcc-4.9.3_openmpi-1.8.8/pkgsrc/2015Q4/bin/python2.7 -c
>   "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/work/tmp/node001.admin.2016-02-09-015538.intx033.31602/pip-build-fORQns/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record
>   /work/tmp/node001.admin.2016-02-09-015538.intx033.31602/pip-7oTcK5-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in
>   /work/tmp/node001.admin.2016-02-09-015538.intx033.31602/pip-build-fORQns/scipy

Unfortunately I don't know what this is supposed to tell me...any ideas?

Comment: When scipy fails to install but other packages do, it's usually something wrong with gfortran, LAPACK, or BLAS. Not familiar with Slurm, but I'd recommend making sure those are properly set up if nobody else has any more specific advice for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you have any links/docs which specificy which packages of gfortran, LAPACK and BLAS are needed? And which versions?

Comment: I don't think it's overly picky. The beginning of the docs here provide some guidance, and there's detailed info for most of the process: http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/linux.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have C, C++ and fortran compilers and BLAS/LAPACK libraries to compile scipy. The easiest option is probably gcc+gfortran+prebuilt atlas, which should just work. For performance, esp with linear algebra, you might want to look into using intel MKL or OpenBLAS.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using gfortran packages, I recommend installing scipy via a scientific package:
[Python XY](http://python-xy.github.io/)
[Anaconda (supports virtual env)](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)